# Why does scan match "" characters when I ask it to match digits?

Tags: ruby, regex

If I run:

```
"607.807-000".scan(/([[:digit:]]*)/)
```

Then I get back the Array:

```
["607", "", "807", "", "000", ""]
```

Why does scan match these `""` characters?

Comment: A more standard regex might be to use `/\d+/` so you won't have the 0 or more times match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is due to the fact that `*` repeats ***zero*** or more times. Hence, at positions with no digits, it will match an empty string. Use `+` instead (repeat ***one*** or more times).